# dnsmasq dhcp-host "bad hex" when using separate file

Tags: dnsmasq

there i wanted to define dhcp reservations in dnsmasq in a separate file with "dhcp-hostsfile" option.
So i added dhcp-hostsfile=PATH_TO_FILE/dhcp.hosts in my dnsmasq.conf.

I then added dhcp reservations in dhcp.hosts e.g.:

```
dhcp-host=44:03:2c:11:ca:9e,192.168.1.101,set:lan,rpi
```

On dnsmasq start i keep getting

```
dnsmasq: bad hex constant at line 1
```

So the file dhcp.hosts gets read but i don't find an error, i checked mac adress and changed the case and i tested simpler versions of the reservation, still  the same result.

So i took the line and pasted it in general dnsmasq.conf - and it suprisingly worked.

Does anybody have a clue whats wrong here?

I tested this with latest alpine linux & dnsmasq in a docker container on a raspberry pi.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found it in the end:
if dnsmasq uses extra dhcp files one is not allowed to add "dhcp-host=" to the entries.

so for example only "44:03:2c:11:ca:9e,192.168.1.101,set:lan,rpi" and it works